# Should there be a Dependable badge?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

This badge would be awarded to users when over 50 of their non-CW answers (and over 50% of all non-CW answers) are voted best in the thread, excluding zero-score answers.

I'm not sure whether the requirements should be changed a little, nor whether the badge should be gold or silver.  Originally I had thought to include best *or* second best answers in a thread, but changed my mind after calculating my own stats on ELU: out of 145 answers, 61% are voted best, 25% second best, 10% neither, and 5% zero-vote (therefore not counted).  I didn't check on anyone else, so I don't know if these badge requirements should be changed at all; I figured that someone with all the SE data would be able to calculate other people's stats much more efficiently.

Comment: You should exclude answers which are the only ones for the question.

Comment: Sometimes there is already a good answer to a question, and it's voted up, but there is a different, good approach that deserves mention. This badge would discourage you from posting this useful information., since (at least on SO) the first rush of views is where most of the votes come from.

Comment: I still think there should be a way to implement the idea of dependability in a badge, even if it isn't exactly this way.  Recognition for users who know their stuff.  Of course, one could argue that rep does that trick, but rep does a lot of tricks which badges can and do supplement.  E.g. why is there a badge for a 100-vote answer when the poster already would usually get in excess of 500 rep and a couple silver badges?  It's an extra.

Comment: I disagree @agf, I think that would be more of an edge case which could fall under the other 50%. Whereas it would encourages users to make *useful* contributions; however, if deleted questions are ignored it might encourage users to delete answer which others would've found useful.

Comment: I don't have an opinion one way or the other on this idea. (I guess -0?) I just don't think it would have an unequivocally positive effect, and I wanted to point out the potential downside.

Comment: I'd like to rather see a badge for someone who after receiving upvotes, deletes his question and then upvotes a better question which receives acceptance.

Comment: @Paŭlo:  But someone is still dependable if his answer is the only one, right?  When uncontested and upvoted, an answer should still be eligible, (or so think I).

Comment: The point is that it is easy being highest voted when your answer is the only one. (On the other hand, this might finally be a badge for people in small tags.) So take your percentage only from the answers which are not the only ones on the question.

Comment: Accepts do not pertain to this, though - votes do.  That makes all the difference.

Comment: @0A0D: There is already the [Disciplined](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/37/disciplined) badge, for deleting, and [Sportsmanship](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/805/sportsmanship) for upvoting many competing answers.

Comment: @Paŭlo: My point is basically that though it may be easy being highest voted *if* your answer is the only one, that is a big *if*.  If you weren't dependable, your answer would either be contested or downvoted (or both).  If your answer is neither contested nor downvoted, it should count, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I've created [a Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1757/dependability) to try this out. It shows your "dependable" answers (those which are the highest voted, but not the only answer, in a non-CW question). Have a look at the number of rows returned to see if you'd be eligible for the badge.